# Sociolinguistics/Psycholinguistics: Does imitation play any role in child language acquisition?

Tags: sociolinguistics, psycholinguistics

Sociolinguistics and Psycholinguistics: Does imitation play any role in child language acquisition?

Comment: I want to say "Yes, definitely", but that isn't really fitting for an answer.

Comment: How is it not _all_ imitation? What else is there?

Comment: @Mitch Well for those who accept the poverty of stimulus argument then some sort of innateness is usually seen as necessary.

Comment: @curious oh ok I get it. But if that's the question, then is there anything other than _those_ two?

Comment: Personally I've always felt that when people argue that 'language acquisition is more than imitation', they usually don't give a good enough definition of imitation to exclude anything as that.